# Dealing with More Comments After Movements to Chat as a User

Tags: discussion, comments, chat

This isn't a huge issue, (and may be a duplicate, but I didn't see another like it), but on a [recent question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/178652/does-something-count-as-dealing-damage-if-its-damage-is-reduced-to-zero) there was quite a bit of discussion on a pair of answers which was ultimately moved to chat. The discussion seemed to generate some heat and unhappiness.

Currently, more comments are being added to those same answers which cover the exact same ground as in the chat and offer nothing new, other than to demonstrate that one additional person supports one or the other answers. They are, essentially, stirring up the same arguments in a way that will clutter the page (rather than leaving it to the chat, where anyone that would like to continue engaging can do so).

If I understand stack policy correctly, these comments are bound for deletion no matter what. But I'm not as clear on what I, as a non-mod user, should do. **Is it worth flagging them for attention?**

I did flag a couple that seemed especially argumentative and unhelpful (my thought being that prompt attention might defuse further heated argument when that entire discussion has been run into the ground already), but I don't want to pester mods with flags that aren't necessary.

Additionally, if flagging is appropriate, is the "no longer needed" flag better/more helpful than a "some other reason" flag?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is worth flagging them for attention, because mods don't view every question and answer every day, so it's how they would know that the comments haven't simmered down in this case. It's unfortunate that only mods can delete comments, but comment deletion is an important part of curating the site, so flag away (one per thread with a custom reason of "this whole comment thread is more arguing after being migrated to chat" is sufficient).

Comment: Users can also delete comments by accumulating enough flags to put further emphasis on the usefulness of flagging them.

Comment: Users can unilaterally delete short comments or comments that match certain regexes (e.g. 'thanks', 'accept this answer', '+1'), etc. Also, normal users can delete comments with enough NLN flags or enough red flags, all without moderator intervention.

Comment: Also I thought moderators get alerted when comment chains reach a certain length... maybe I'm confusing that with multiple rollbacks (which I know alerts mods)...

Comment: @TylerH We are, but the autoflag cares about comments posted, not actual length and is often what prompts the initial move. Subsequent comments are less likely to raise such a flag (so use your manual ones).